# python 2.7 subprocess catch and print output/result from airodump-ng executed terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, output

Im trying to catch the result from airodump-ng through a opened terminal.  The terminal was opened inside a subprocess.

I want to catch and print the output from airodump-ng. The idea is to open a new terminal as shown in the code, let airodump-ng run until the user crtl+c, and then collect all the output from airodump-ng in a variable for later usage.

**Im still using Pything 2.7**

Here is my original part

```
cmd_line = 'gnome-terminal --command="airodump-ng mon0"'
airodump = subprocess.Popen(cmd_line, shell=True, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Attempt 1

```
out = airodump.communicate()[0]
print out
```

Attempt 2

```
or line in airodump.stdout:
    print line
```

Any ideas to what i do wrong here?

Comment: What result do you get when you roun your program? You don't mention what result or error you get, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: No results man. Just a lot of nothing.  I got some errors here and there, locked processes and so on.  The thing i wanted to achieve was a cheap way to not use scapy.  I think i might have to use scapy.  If you have some idea how to solve my issue, by not using or using my code i would be happy i see it still.  But i am going ot use scapy in my next example, because thats soooo much more easy to control.  I hope you follow my thoughts. :)

Comment: To conclude some tests.. Attempt 1 returns a blank line.

Comment: Attempt 2 dosent give me any visual result.